# how to close the current view controller and enter a new one without an arrow in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

For example, this is my entry view controller:
[image]

When I click the `login` button, it will enter the second view controller:
[image]

Then I click `Functions`, it will enter :
[image]

Now I hope when I click `logout` button on the last view controller , it can enter the first view controller without the arrow and `Functions` on the top left conner:
[image]

I hope that when I click `logout`, this app can restart from the very first view controller (exactly like the same photo), I don't want this part shows up:
[image]

Tried this way:
[image]

tried this way:
[image]

Comment: Try this `let vc : AnyObject! = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mainPage")
            self.mainViewController(vc as! UIViewController, sender: vc)` or change the segue to `Show Detail (e.g. Replace)`

Comment: I did use Show Detail (e.g. Replace), but it does't work either.

Comment: Sorry there was a mistake in my answer i meant `let vc : AnyObject! = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mainPage")            self.showDetailViewController(vc as! UIViewController, sender: vc)` instead, i apologize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have configured a segue in your storyboard from the Logout button to the Login screen.  If you want to use a segue to go back to the login screen, you must use an unwind segue, which is setup differently than a normal segue.  Performing a normal segue as you do now will create a new Login screen and push it onto the navigation stack.

First create a method in your login view controller as follows:

```
@IBAction func logoutUnwindSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    // Intentionally left blank
}
```

Then connect a segue from your logout button to the little orange icon at the top of the scene that says Exit when you mouse over it (and pick `logoutUnwindSegue:`).

[image]

Comment: Funny.  I didn't even notice this time.

Answer (score 2):

In your view controller, instead of pushing a new view controller onto the navigation controller, you want to pop all the view controllers so you're back at the root. Luckily, theres a method for that.

```
self.navigationContorller.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Comment: Tried. But it seems I need to edit another part of code, too ?

Comment: Should I delete the original relationship between these two view controllers?

Comment: You need to remove the segue from the logout button and just call a method that has this one line of code in it.